# Auto-scrolling a Listview in WP8.1 results in a refresh animation

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a new universal app for WP8.1 and am having some difficulties with a ListView inside of a Hub control.

This ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection of chat messages, and this ObservableCollection is updated with new messages periodically. On each update, I scroll to the bottom of the ListView. Right now, I accomplish this with the following:

```
this.vm.Messages.Add(new Message() { Body="Test Message", MateName="Test User", SendTime=DateTimeOffset.UtcNow });
list_messages.ScrollIntoView(this.vm.Messages.Last());
```

Where `list_messages` is the ListView with an ItemsSource bound to `this.vm.Messages`.

What results is a bit hard to demonstrate with images; the list scrolls to the bottom, but ALL items fade in again as if the entire list is being refreshed.

Here's a progression when a new item is added to the end of the list:

[image: Listview progression when adding a new item]

It would be great if just the /last/ item faded in... but instead the whole list seems to refresh. What could be going wrong here?

Here's the basic XAML in a nutshell for good measure.

```
<ListView
    x:Uid="list_messages"
    x:Name="list_messages"
    Margin="12,-12,6,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="list_messages_Loaded">
    ...
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem> Textblock w/ bindings, etc. </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Something could be raising the OnPropertyChanged event for the Messages property. Set a break point on the property and see if it breaks when you add a message.

Comment: its true, I discovered that when calling this method the whole items are re-drawn. I have  a custom content presenter inside my data template, and when calling ScrollIntoView(items.Last()) all content presenter's constructors are called again. I advice you to create a custom listview in which you retrieve the scrollviewer and therefore you can scroll to vertical offset and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you can try this: [Perfect ListView](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2015/06/10/listview-how-to-prevent-glitches-during-scrolling/)